# How to prevent duplicate phone number in account using triggers?

Tags: visualforce

How to prevent duplicate phone number in account using triggers?
sir, i.e the phone number is already use in one account,,now use that phone number in another account.so on that time how to prevent that duplicate phone number? and how o display the error??

Comment: Do you mean if you enter a phone number on one account should not be same on any of the other accounts. specify in your question by editing it.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Do you want to prevent duplicate phone numbers in account? Where are you using triggers ?

Comment: How have you tried it - and why can't you solve it ? Please specify the exact issue you're having so we can help you accordingly.

Comment: Is it acceptable if you use a custom phone number instead of native phone number?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you want to use triggers? There is no need for triggers for the use-case you've described.

If all you want to do is stop people creating duplicate records and show an error message you can use the new [Duplicate Management](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_prevention_map_of_tasks.htm&language=en_US) features that were added in the [Spring '15 release](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_sales_duplicate_management_intro.htm).

Answer (score -1):

If a custom field is ok then create a custom phone number field in an account object and make the field as unique.